# is there a way to crop multiple netcdf files using CDO?

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate

I have multiple global climate model (GCM) data files. I successfully cropped one file but it takes time to crop one by one over thousand data files manually. How can I do multiple crops? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a loop combined with some patience... ;-)

```
for file in $(ls *.nc) ; do
    cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 $file ${file%???}_crop.nc 
done
```

the `%???` chops off the ".nc" and then I add "_crop" to the output file name...

Answer (score 1):

*I know I am a little late to add to the answer, but still wanted to add my knowledge for those who would still pass through this question.*

I followed the code given by Adrian Tompkins and it seems to work exceptionally fine. But there are somethings to be considered which I'd like to highlight. And because I am still novice at programming, please forgive my much limited answer. So here are my findings for the code above to work...

1. The code used calls **CDO (Climate Data Operators)** which is a non-GUI standalone program that can be utilized in Linux terminal. In my case, I used it in my Windows 10 through **WSL** (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). There are good videos in youtube for using WSL in youtube.
2. **The code** initially did not work for until I made a slight change. The code

   ```
   for file in $(ls *.nc) ; do
         cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 $file ${file%???}_crop.nc 
   done
   ```

worked for me when I wrote it as

```
for file in $(ls *.nc) ; do
    cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 $file ${file%???}_crop.nc;
done
```

see the presence of  a `;` in the code in line 2.

3. The entire code (in my case to work) was put in a text file (can be put as script in other formats as well) and passed as a **script in the Linux terminal**. The procedure to execute the script file is as follows:

3.a) create the '.txt' file containing the script above. *Do note that the directory should be checked in all steps.*

3.b) make the file executable by running the command line
`chmod +x <name_of_the_textfile_with_extension>` in the terminal.

3.c) run the script (in my case it is the textfile) by running the command line `./<name_of_the_textfile_with_extension>`

The above procedures will give you cropped netcdf files for the corresponding netcdf files in the same folder.

cheers!

Comment: hi, nice detailed answer - note that the ";" is not needed if you have the code in a script and you hit "carriage return" to make sure the "done" is on a new line.  If you cut and paste the code from the web, it may have picked it up as a continuous line.  In fact from the command line you can write "for file in list ; do cdo command in out ; done" on one line, while in a script you can also put the "do" on a new line and not use semi-colon at all...

Comment: Thank You so Much Adrian! I am learning so much from people who have big and generous hearts like yours.  much appreciated...