# how to I add a specific variable from a list of netcdf files to a different one?

Tags: linux, bash, netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have already realized that I can use the command ncks in my terminal to transfer a variable I need (temperature) from one .nc file to another that has the same structure but instead of temperature it has current data (uo, vo). My question is, how do I create a loop that takes the temperature variable from each of these temperature .nc files and transfer it to the sea current data of the same date?

I have already tried creating the below script, although because i'm a beginner in programming I am well aware that it is probably very wrong, but this is the logic that I am going for

```
for filei in $(ls *TEMP-MFSe3r1-MED-b20200901_re-sv01.00.nc) ; do
        for filej in $(ls *RFVL-MFSe3r1-MED-b20200901_re-sv01.00.nc) ; do
                ncks -v thetao $filei $filej
        done
done
```

The code that I have written doesn't succeed in the purpose that I wanted for it. While I would like for the code to take each *TEMP netcdf file, take from it the temperature variable and append it to the equivalent RFVL file, what it does is run the loop too many times and try to append that temperature variable to all the *RFVL files. In addition, I realize that I never specified what my files are named, here is an example:

```
20130701_d-CMCC--RFVL-MFSe3r1-MED-b20200901_re-sv01.00_crop.nc
20130701_d-CMCC--TEMP-MFSe3r1-MED-b20200901_re-sv01.00_crop.nc
```

The command in question that I would like to loop, which works as intended is:

`ncks -v thetao *TEMP*.nc *RFVL*.nc`

which is, it takes from `*TEMP*.nc` file the thetao variable and appends it to the `*RFVL*.nc` file, the with the only slight problem that after I execute this command it asks me:

`ncks: 20130701_d-CMCC--RFVL-MFSe3r1-MED-b20200901_re-sv01.00_crop.nc exists---'e'xit, 'o'verwrite (i.e., clobber existing file), or 'a'ppend (i.e., replace duplicate variables in, and add metadata and new variables to, existing file) (e/o/a)?`

in order to know how I would like to proceed, to which I reply with: `a`, but I would prefer to find a way to also automate from the command itself so it doesn't ask me every time.
Just to clarify, the two sets of files that i'm working with have the exact same name except of the 4 letters in the middle that indicate the type of data stored on the files.

In case someone has a better method to suggest, what I basically want to do is from every *TEMP file, which includes the variable thetao, the variable for potential heat, I want to append that variable to the equivalent (of the same day) *RFVL file, in order to create a list of netcdf files that have temperature and sea currrent data in them (I have 60 files of each type)

I apologize for the incomplete question, this is my first time posting on stack overflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you clarify what your question is? You have tagged netcdf and cdo-climate. Yet, you aren't using CDO. And the question seems to purely be about bash scripts? Also, you have told us what you have tried, but you haven't told us if it is not working. Is it?

Comment: Paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and apply the recommended fixes to your code. Aside from this, I don't understand the question. Describe in what respect the code you have posted does something different from what you expect it to do.

Comment: @RobertWilson sorry for the vague question, it's the first time i'm posting on stack overflow. I tagged cdo-climate in case anyone had an alternative proposal using cdo that would work, instead of what I tried, and netcdf because i'm trying to to add a variable to a list of netcdf files. The question is mainly around bash scripts but also if anyone has a suggestion using cdo. Also no, sadly It doesn't work, it loops over all of the files with the sea current values adding in to them the temperature value, before starting the same with the next temperature file

Comment: @user1934428 it doesn't loop like I need it to, I need it to take the temperature value from every temperature netcdf file and append it to the equivalent sea current file, but what it does is append the temperature variable from the first file to all of my sea current files. Plus it asks me to either exit the script, overwrite the pre-existing data, or append to the existing data the new variable, I would like to automate that decision but I don't know how.

Comment: This information should go into the question, not into a comment, but for a start, do a small calculation: Say that your outer loop loops over m files and the inner loop loops over n files; this means that your `ncks` will be invoked m*n times. Isn't this too many? I think you need to create somehow a mapping which associates each TEMP file with one (or just a few) RFVL files. Since I don't know anything about your application domain, I can't suggest a suitable mapping here.

Comment: I am trying to come up with a solution similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101040/is-there-a-way-to-crop-multiple-netcdf-files-using-cdo

Comment: @user1934428 I just edited the question to make it more complete. Yes you are correct, the loop runs too many times, but I am not sure how to do the mapping that you are suggesting.

Comment: you've provided two *.nc files; please update the question with the complete `ncks` command you would run against these two files and confirm whether or not said `ncks` command does what you want

Comment: I'm ***guessing*** you want to match a specific `RFVL` file with a specific `TEMP` file; if this is true, please update the question with details on what portions of the filenames we're supposed to use to match a `RFVL` file with its associated `TEMP` file; is it by any chance as simple as *match the entire filename except for the 4-character `RFVL` vs `TEMP`*?

Comment: Before we can discuss, how to **do** the mapping, you first have to **define** the mapping. Defining a mapping has more to do with set theory than with programming.

Comment: @markp-fuso hey, sorry again for the missing info from my original question. So yes, if I run the command `ncks -v thetao .nc1 .nc2` it works as expected, with the only small problem being that once I run the command it asks me this `ncks: 20130701_d-CMCC--RFVL-MFSe3r1-MED-b20200901_re-sv01.00_crop.nc exists---'e'xit, 'o'verwrite (i.e., clobber existing file), or 'a'ppend (i.e., replace duplicate variables in, and add metadata and new variables to, existing file) (e/o/a)?` and I chose -a ,which I would prefer to automate but am not sure how

Comment: @markp-fuso also, to your second question, thats exactly it, all of the filename is the same except for those 4 letters which indicate the variables stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- each `TEMP` file has a matching `RVFL` file
- each matching pair of `RFVL / TEMP` files has the same exact name, except for the 4-character `RFVL` vs `TEMP`
- the 4-character `RFVL / TEMP` only shows up once in a file name (ie, we don't have to worry about names like `123_TEMP_TEMP_789.nc` or `abc_RFVL_TEMP_xyz.nc`)
- OP's sample `ncks` call is valid and does what OP wants it to (when provided with matching `RVFL / TEMP` files)
- each `TEMP` file is guaranteed to have a value for the variable `thetao`; otherwise OP will need to provide additional details on how to determine if, and how to process, a `TEMP` file does *not* have a value for `thetao`
- don't have to worry about OP running this process twice thus appending a duplicate `thetao` entry to the `RVFL` file; otherwise OP will need to provide more details on how to determine if, and how to process, a `RVFL` file that already contains a `thetao` entry

General design:

- get a list of `TEMP` file names
- make a copy of the `TEMP` file name and replace `TEMP` with `RFVL`
- run the `ncks` command

One idea:

```
for src in *TEMP*.nc
do
    tgt="${src/TEMP/RFVL}"
    ncks -v thetao "${src}" "${tgt}"
done
```

Comment: This solution seems to work fine, thank you! Only slight problem is that once I run it I need to respond with an -a to the question of `e/o/a` that I mentioned in my comment above for every file it goes through, but I had that problem before too and i'm sure if I start looking around in the `ncks` documentation I will find a solution. But again, thank you

Comment: From what it seems, all I needed to do in order to automate the process without having to clarify each time between `e/o/a` was to put an `-A` in the command. So now it seems to be working perfectly! Thank you again for your solution. Just to clarify, the final code i'm going to be using is                                                                                                     `for src in *TEMP*.nc
do
    tgt="${src/TEMP/RFVL}"
    ncks -A -v thetao "${src}" "${tgt}"
done` so basically the code you wrote with the addition of `-A`