# invoking an awk script inside a bash loop

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I have a few hundreds of file that I want to combine 2 by 2 files. With the help of @markp-fuso I can combine the 2 by 2 files together using a awk script which combines correct the 2 files at the time:

`awk -f merge_join.awk -v f1=acor.PW.VMF1.2020.out -v f2=acor.PW.GPT2.2020.out > acor.VMF1-GPT2-combinat.log`

Now, my problem is that I want to invoke the awk script in a bash loop. The files that I want to combine are in pairs of two, for example:

```
acor.PW.GPT2.2020.out  
acor.PW.VMF1.2020.out  
aubg.PW.GPT2.2020.out  
aubg.PW.VMF1.2020.out  
autn.PW.GPT2.2020.out  
autn.PW.VMF1.2020.out  
axpv.PW.GPT2.2020.out  
axpv.PW.VMF1.2020.out

....................
```

The common part of the files are the first four letters that I want to combine. I have tried in bash script to invoke the awk script but without any success.

```
    #!/bin/bash
     a=VMF1
     b=GPT2
     for f in *VMF1*
     do
     i=$(echo $f | awk '{print substr($1,1,4)}')
        ./merge_join.awk -v f1="$i" -v f2="$i*$b*.out" > $i.$a-$b-combinat.log

    done
```

Comment: Show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you should be able to use the same code as from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77783544) (to the posted duplicate); `src/tgt` become `f1/f2`, `TEMP/RFVL` are replaced with `VMF1/GPT2`; obviously the `ncks` call would be replaced with your `awk` call

Comment: the assignment of `i` can be simplified using `bash` substring functionality, ie, `i="${f:0:4}"`

Comment: after reviewing the duplicate question and associated answer, if you still have issues then consider updating this question with your latest coding attempt (though deleting this question and asking a new question will likely be faster)

Comment: You shouldn't need to call awk in a loop to do this, just 1 call to awk should do it, but the small code snippet with no sample input (just a list of file names) and no expected output make it impossible to help you. Please create and post a [mcve] that demonstrates your needs and which we can copy/paste to test with and test a potential solution with.

Comment: Thank you @markp-fuso it works and also for the simplified bash substring functionality.

Comment: Dear @Ed Morton I have posted a problem regarding the combination of two files - which represents the original problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78057415/invoking-an-awk-script-inside-a-bash-loop?noredirect=1#comment137611082_78057415 and I needed a bash to run the awk script recommended for multiple files. 
Thank you!

Comment: Regarding "I have posted a problem regarding the combination of two files - which represents the original problem" - what original problem? You say you have an awk script that does something but didn't tell/show us that awk script nor tell us what that something is. Regarding "I needed a bash to run the awk script recommended for multiple files" - almost certainly not, you probably just need a change to your awk script or a different awk script, but without a [mcve] for your current problem (see the first comment you got above) we're just guessing.